# Selenium how to press two different key combinations after starting up the browser

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So im trying to load a website with node selenium, and when im at its root, just press two different key combinations, waiting a bit between each other.

So far ive gotten this

```
    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    
    const Keys = webdriver.Key
    const By = webdriver.By
    
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder().
       withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
       build();
    
       
    driver.get('https://example.com');
    
    //this element is supposed to be some almost root container, but ideally i dont want to select anything, just press the keys.
    
    driver.findElement(By.id('canvas-container')).sendKeys('webdriver', Keys.CTRL + Keys.F5);
driver.findElement(By.id('canvas-container')).sendKeys('webdriver', Keys.CTRL + Keys.F5);
//wait 2-5 sec
driver.findElement(By.id('canvas-container')).sendKeys('webdriver', Keys.CTRL + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.C);
```

That doesn't work because

> Element  is not reachable by keyboard

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't want to select anything, just press the keys ActionSequence is what you are looking for!
I'm not really familiar with Selenium on node.js, but from what I have found the syntax is something like this:

```js
let action = new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.CTRL + Keys.F5);

action.perform()
```

Comment: webdriver.ActionSequence is not a constructor